# Print a number which is out of long range

Tags: java

When I run this code and use a value greater than the range of long, then the output is "0 can't be fitted anywhere".
I would like to output:
"x (which I have given input which is outside the range of long) can't be fitted anywhere"

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] argh) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            long x = 0;
            try {
                x = sc.nextLong();
                System.out.println(x + " can be fitted in:");
                if (x >= -128 && x <= 127)
                    System.out.println("* byte");
                if (x >= -32768 && x <= 32767)
                    System.out.println("* short");
                if (x >= -2147483648 && x <= 2147483647)
                    System.out.println("* int");
                if (x >= -9223372036854775808l && x <= 9223372036854775807l)
                    System.out.println("* long");

                // Complete the code
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(x + " can't be fitted anywhere.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your `Scanner` at the end: `sc.close();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(x + " can't be fitted anywhere.");
}
```

by

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println(sc.next() + " can't be fitted anywhere.");
}
```

`next()` will get as a `String` the token that wasn't retrieved by `nextLong()` due to the exception.

Comment: Florent Bayle thanks in advance i want the same answer you have given.but can you be specific it is done internally by the jvm ???when the range of long is not matched then it will automatically will be transferred to sc.next()??how??

Comment: @RakeshYadav `sc.nextLong()` will `throw` an `InputMismatchException` when the next token cannot be parsed as a `long`. When it's the case, you will enter the `catch` block. `sc.next()` will read the next token (the one that wasn't read by `sc.nextLong()`) and return it as a `String` (so it doesn't have to fit in a `long`, as it's a `String`).

Answer (score 2):

If the number is out of the range of `long` you can't use a `long`.

Use the class [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) that hasn't this kind of limit.

From javadoc:

> Immutable **arbitrary-precision** integers

Answer (score 2):

BigInteger bg = new BigInteger("yourNumber");

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

As you already encountered, you can't use `long` for this. [`Scanner.nextLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong--) will throw an [`InputMismatchException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) when the value can't be represented as a `long`.

You can use a String and try to parse it:

```
long x = 0;
String input = "";
try {
    input = sc.nextLine();
    x = Long.parseLong(input);
    System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
    // rest of code
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println(input + " can't be fitted anywhere.");
}
```

Note that I changed the catched exception: you should avoid catching `Exception` and prefer the most specific `Exception`.